# GMTOFF calculation in r

Tags: r

I have date assigned to a

```
%let a=06jul2016
```

I want to create two variables based on two calculation done in sas

```
b=dhms("&a"d,00,00,00)-gmtoff(),IS8601DT23.3))
c=dhms("&a"d,24,00,00)-gmtoff(),IS8601DT23.3))
```

Note &a will take the value 06jul2016

Output

```
 b is 2016-07-06T04:00:00.00
 c is 2016-07-07T04:00:00.00
```

I want to create a new variable D with value of b and c with few strings.

```
D=tz=2016-07-06T04:00:00.00&tz2016-07-07T04:00:00.00
```

How to get the above result using R

Comment: `gmtoff()` stores the raw UTC offset from the current machine that the SAS code is running on, if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard, as R will automatically convert any dates to the current timezone if you don't explicitly mention a timezone:

```
a <- "06jul2016"
#Assuming you are in GMT+4, otherwise use the explicit
#conversion commented out below
b <- as.POSIXct(a,format="%d%b%Y")
#b <- as.POSIXct(a,format="%d%b%Y",tz="Etc/GMT+4")
attr(b, "tzone") <- "UTC"
format(b, "%Y%-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS2")
#"2016-07-06T04:00:00.00"
```

To get the additional day, try:

```
format(b + as.difftime(1, units="days"), "%Y%-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS2")
#[1] "2016-07-07T04:00:00.00"
```